# how to take value from drop down list by ajax and send it to php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a drop down list of some categories names, I want to take the name of the selected category by using ajax and send them to the same php page that the ajax script is inside it, here is my ***new code***:

create action code:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new News;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

                if(isset($_POST['category']))
                       $category = $_POST['category'];
                   else
                       $category = NULL;

        if(isset($_POST['News']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['News'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model, 'category'=>$category
        ));
    }
```

form code:

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo CHtml::label('Choose category to add from',''); ?>
                <?php $data = array('celebrities'=>'Celebrities', 'events'=>'Events', 'videos'=>'Videos', 'editorials'=>'Editorials'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('category', '', $data); ?>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $("#category").change(function(){
                var category = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url:'/tonyward/index.php/news/create',
                data:{category:category},
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'html',
                success:function(data) {
                    console.log(data.category)
                },
                cache:false
            });
        });
        </script>

        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'idItem'); ?>
                <?php $data = array('celebrities'=>$category); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('subcategory', '', $data); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'idItem'); ?>
    </div>
```

now how should the data of the second drop down list will changed ?

***old code :***

```
<div class="row">
            <?php echo CHtml::label('Choose category to add from',''); ?>
                    <?php $data = array('celebrities'=>'Celebrities', 'events'=>'Events', 'videos'=>'Videos', 'editorials'=>'Editorials'); ?>
            <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('category', '', $data); ?>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#category").change(function(){

            $("#category").change(function(){

                var category = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:window.location.href,
                    type:'GET',
                    data:{category:category},
                    dataType:'json',
                    cache:false,
                    success:function(data){

                    },
                });
            });
    </script>

    <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['category'])){

            $category = $_GET['category'];

            echo "<script>alert('done');</script>";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: what is your specific problem?

Comment: Do you know that your page AJAX call returns the **WHOLE PAGE** plus `<script>alert('done');</script>`? Which is really **NOT** `json` as specified by the `dataType`. Therefore, I expect that there will be a parse error and there's no `.error` handler to fire. And if the call was to be successful, you do not render what's is returned ... therefore you wont see the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how did I solved my problem?

1. I have created a function named `selectedCategory()`.
2. `selectedCategory()` is `renderPartial` the html code of the drop down list, that are written in _categoryItems.php.
3. I called an ajax function on the change of the first drop down category `('#category')`.
4. the ajax function will be posted to `selectedCategory()`, and finally it will load html data (on success) in a specific div.

here is the codes:

***form and ajax function code:***

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo CHtml::label('Choose category to add from',''); ?>
                <?php $data = array('Celebrities'=>'Celebrities', 'Events'=>'Events', 'Videos'=>'Videos', 'Editorials'=>'Editorials'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('category', '', $data, array(
                    'empty'=>'select category'
                )); ?>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {

                document.getElementById('itemslabel').style.display='none';
            });

            $("#category").change(function(){

                document.getElementById('itemslabel').style.display='block';
                var category = $(this).val();

                if(category === ''){

                    document.getElementById('items').style.display='none';
                }

                else{

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'/tonyward/index.php/news/selectedCategory',
                        data:{category:category},
                        async:true,
                        type:'POST',
                        dataType:'html',
                        success:function(data) {

                            document.getElementById('items').style.display='block';
                            $('#categoryItems').html(data);
                        },
                        cache:false
                    });
                }
        });
        </script>

        <div class="row" id="items">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'idItem', array('id'=>'itemslabel')); ?>
                <div id="categoryItems"></div>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'idItem'); ?>
    </div>
```

***action `selectedCategory` code:***

```
public function actionSelectedCategory(){

            if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){

                $category = $_POST['category'];

                $this->renderPartial('_categoryItems', array(
                   'category'=>$category 
                ));
            }
        }
```

***`_categoryItems` code:***

```
<?php $data = CHtml::listData($category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'thumbtitle'); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('subcategory', '', $data); ?>
```

*Note: I displayed and hid some elements by my js code.*

Answer (score 1):

A `select` tag has no `href` so `this.href` isn't going to produce a valid URL for your AJAX.

Comment: please try to put such notes in comments, this not an answer, although I upvoted.

Comment: @MD.MD this certainly is a valid answer. Please explain why it isn't. You haven't idendified what your problem is, or provided any troubleshooting information or specifics as to what issue is

Comment: because its not a complete answer.

Comment: it is as complete as the question. Trying to help but since you haven't specified what your issue is, this part of code will fail.

Comment: my issue is the var `category` didn't been received by the PHP code

Comment: well you need to provide a valid url as I've noted in my answer

Comment: I have used `windows.location.href', valid ?

Comment: no...look in console...`windows` is undefined, try `window`. Inspect the actual request in newtork tab of console

Comment: sry I mean `window.location.href` , but php still not functioning.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that your page AJAX call returns the **WHOLE PAGE** plus `<script>alert('done');</script>`? Which is really **NOT** `json` as specified by the `dataType` option. Therefore, I expect that there will be a `parse error` and there's no `.error` handler to fire. And if the call was to be `success`ful, **you do not render what's is returned** ... therefore you wont see the alert.

**Suggestions**

1. Change your PHP script so that when `category` is set only the code within the `if` block is returned
2. Instead of `<script>alert('done');</script>` just use `done` ==> `echo "done"
3. In the `success` handler include `alert( data )`
4. Change `dataType` to `text`
5. Include an `error` handler just in case.
6. When asking a question based on client-side code it's usually helpful to include the HTML (rendered by your browser) of the relevant part(s) instead of server-side code. I cannot tell what `category` in the PHP code is: `id` or `name` ... and many others may have the same issue and would avoid the question.

Comment: Your latest edit to your question has made all the comments and answers irrelevant. I would prefer that you restore the original question **and as a new question**, but that's just me. Alternatively, you could edit your question in such a way as to show it's various versions.